# Передача ссылки на Activity в AsyncTask, почему плохо и как можно было иначе

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Всё что внизу описано, это то как я использовал интерфейс для получения результата из  AsynckTack в главный поток, используя `CallBack`. Почему мне сказали, что плохо , что я передал ссылку на активити в `AsyncTask`? И как лучше надо было это исполнить?

Вот в классе `MainActivity` вызываю такой метод и как видите передаю ссылку на активити в `AsyncTack`

```
private void UploadData() {
        String url = "https://qwerty.ru" ;
        AsyncUploadingData asyncUploadingData = new 
        AsyncUploadingData(this);
        asyncUploadingData.execute(url);
    }
}
```

В `AsyncTack`  вложен интерфейс

```
interface AsyncResult {
        void getResult(String answer);
    }
```

Объявлен  `private AsyncResult mCallback;`

И в конструкторе принимаю ссылку на активити. И неявно привожу к интерфейсу(правильно так выразиться?)

```
 AsyncUploadingData(AsyncResult mCallback) {
        this.mCallback = mCallback;
    }
```

И в опеределенный момент вызываю метод интерфейса, а интерфейс подключен в `MainActivity`

```
 mCallback.getResult(answer);
```

Comment: если активити уничтожится будет утечка памяти

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему мне сказали, что плохо , что я передал ссылку на активити в `AsyncTask`?

Хранение ссылки на активити в `AsyncTask` чревато тем, что в случае уничтожения переданной активити в момент работы асинстаска:

а) Произойдет утечка памяти, так как GC не сможет убрать из памяти активити, так как на нее будет хранится ссылка (в случае с strong reference);

б) Вызов методов активити, в лучшем случае, ни к чему не приведет, а в худшем –
 будут возникать ошибки.

Первая проблема решается хранением активити в виде weak reference, однако вторая проблема остается.

> И как лучше надо было это исполнить?

Существует большое количество способов решения данной проблемы.

Например, можно воспользоваться лоадерами или `retain`-фрагментами (лоадеры сохраняют состояние как раз с помощью `retain`-фрагментов).

Можно использовать различные библиотеки, например [`Chronos`](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/Chronos).

Если используете MVP, то можно воспользоваться библиотекой [Moxy](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy), которая, в частности, решает возникшую у Вас проблему.

Comment: Chronos устарела) Я вот сейчас на ней проект поддерживаю и не стал бы советовать пробовать эту штуку в новых проектах)

Comment: post_zeew, насчет первой проблемы понятно. Проблема будет, когда активити в Стэке , а из AsyncTask'a к ней обратится , так? Насчет лоадеров и retain-фрагментов сейчас почитаю.Как только решил что вроде всё понятно, еще какие то новые штуки вылезают.. Вроде на офф документации написано, что из AsyncTaska вернуть, что либо в главный поток, используя интерфейс, единственный верный способ. А тут вон еще грабли

Comment: @Turalllb, Когда активити задестроится, то ее не будет нигде, за исключением ссылки в асинстаске. Система не будет ее воспринимать как активити в принципе.

Comment: post_zeew, с первой проблемой разобрался, а вот по второй никак не пойму.  Прочитал про retain-фрагементы, понял что они нужны для сохранения состояния при изменении конфигурации. Но никак не пойму как они связаны со второй проблемой и вообще в чем вторая проблема заключается? Связано ли вторая проблема именно с передачей ссылки на активити в AsyckTask или с любой передачей ссылки на активити? Говорите вызов методов активити ни к чему не приведет. Какой вызов? Видать я в своем приложении не испытываю описанной вами проблемы и поэтому мне трудно понять о чем вы говорите

Comment: @Turalllb, Какие действия происходят в методе `getResult`?

Comment: post_zeew, я там принимаю строковую переменную из AsynckTask (это Json ответ сервера) и далее работает парсер и результат отображается в List и в Spinner .  Может быть в моем случае и не возникает той проблемы, что вы описали, но замечание мне могли сделать потому , что это не хороший подход и может привести в дальнейшем к ошибкам . И я скорее хотел бы от вас услышать о ситуации в которой это станет проблемой, т.е. в каком случае вызов методов активити ни к чему не приведет или даже приведет к ошибкам?

Comment: @Turalllb, Вот Вы передали ссылку на активити в асинстаск. Далее началась работа по загрузке данных, далее активити пересоздалась. Затем данные загрузились и Вы вызвали коллбэк. Этот коллбэк привязан к старой активити, у которой вызвался метод `onDestroy()` и она витает в воздухе, так как в данный момент на экране уже другая активити (новая). В коллбэке Вы пытаетесь отобразить данные на **старой** активити, которой уже нет на экране. Вот в этом заключается проблема.

Comment: post_zeew, да , точно. Я что-то совсем не в ту сторону смотрел. Я понял как используя мягкие ссылки не дать AsyckTask обратиться к несуществующей активити, а не подумал, что он как-то должен передать свои данные в новую активити. Но именно, по сохранению фрагментов, есть еще вопросы, создам отдельный.

Answer (score 3):

Да особой разницы в целом нет, будь то интерфейс или прямая ссылка на `Activity`. Не советовали туда передавать `Activity` так как нарушает инкапсуляцию.

Так-то, конечно же, можно передавать `Activity`, но хотя бы заворачивать её тогда уж в `WeakReference`.

```
WeakReference<Activity> mWeakActivity;

public AsyncUploadingData(Activity activity) {
   mWeakActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
}
```

Но, независимо от подхода, при вызове из `onPostExecute` нужно проверять ссылку на `null`, так как к моменту завершения `AsyncTack` `Activity` уже могла быть пересоздана.

Comment: Ну в моем случае всего одно активити и если её нет, значит приложение закрыто. Но я немного запутался: Если я сверну активити и обратно вызову ведь onCreate не срабатывает, это та же самая активити? (исключим случай поворота экрана)

Comment: АА..а что если активити будет в onPause, а я в неё передам что нибудь методом обратного вызова? При восстановлении активити, оно что нибудь получит или будут ошибки?